# in GWT, How to add a row on top of header of celltable?

Tags: gwt, header, header-files, celltable, gwtquery

This is very interesting, how can we add a row on top of header of celltable in GWT?

Ok, Say,GWT Header only support sorting, but i want to do other stuffs on each of the column as well (such filter, hide, ....)

So i want to add a row on top of header of celltable. On the row, there r many button, each button is corresponding to a column. When user click a button then they can do other stuffs like filter or hide.

Example:

Button1 - Button2 - Button3.

Header1 - Header2 - Header3.

Cell 11 - Cell 12 - Cell 13.

Cell 21 - Cell 22 - Cell 23.

more cell....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way using GWT is extending the `CellTable` implementation and create your own hacking code in the part where `CellTable` creates its header. Also you have to consider adding many methods to add buttons, handlers etc. I have deal with this before and it is a very tedious task.

But you have the option of modifying the `DOM` once the table has been created. There are many ways to do that, but the easier way I know is using gwtquery aka gquery.

In your case I would use a code like this:

```java
 // import gquery stuff
 import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;

 // Create your table and add its colums
 final CellTable<MyObject> celltable = ...
 [...] 

 // Delay until the table has been full rendered, I use gquery delay() because 
 // of its syntax but you could use Scheduler or Timer as well
 $(celltable).delay(0, new Function(){
    public void f() {

     // Now we add a div to each header, you could add any html though
     $("th", celltable).prepend($("<div class='mypanel' style='height: 40px'/>"));

     // gquery's widget plugin is able to promote certain dom elements 
     // like div/th/... etc into HTMLpanels
     GQuery panels = $(".mypanel", celltable).as(Widgets).panel();

     // gquery can return a sorted list of widgets asociated with a set of elements
     List<HTMLPanel> list = panels.widgets(HTMLPanel.class);

     // Now you can add any gwt widget to your panels
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       list.get(i).add(new Button("Button: " + i));
     }
   }
});
```

Here a screenshot of what produces the code above:

[image: CellTable with buttons]

This approach implies that you have to import [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) into your project, but honestly, I dont imagine me working on a GWT project without it :-),

Gquery helps a lot when designers ask for enhancing gwt-widgets and you don't want to enforce tweaks (which most times implies complex coding and investigation) to do very simple things like to modify the dom generated by a widget.

Additionally Gquery comes with a lot of stuff you can take advantage of, like easy ajax syntax, promises, plugins, use js methods and properties without writing jsni, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its almost not possible,that adding a row on top of header which is out of`cell table.`

But the functionality you said can acheive  by adding a horizantalpanel with `zero padding` and adding your  `buttons` to that panel (obviously widths of buttons should same as your columns widths and with little css. )

On clicking of each button you can do the operations or sorting on`celltable.`

*disclaimer:this is my possible solution*.

Answer (score 0):

Since GWT 2.5 it should be possible to provide a custom `HeaderBuilder` or extend [AbstractHeaderOrFooterBuilder](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHeaderOrFooterBuilder.java?r=10597)/[DefaultHeaderOrFooterBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DefaultHeaderOrFooterBuilder.html) to solve your problem.
You can have a look at the this [CustomTableGrid](http://showcase2.jlabanca-testing.appspot.com/#!CwCustomDataGrid) showcase. 
It defines a custom `CellTableBuilder` but the same principles should also apply to the `HeaderBuilder` interface.